# Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI

Tags: flutter

```
Image.network(
   height: 210.0,
   widget.model!.thumbnailUrl!,
   fit: BoxFit.cover,
   errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception,StackTrace? stackTrace) {
     return const Text('');
   },
),
```

i have fetched image from firebase iam not able to see it on screen this is my code

Comment: What is the value of `widget.model!.thumbnailUrl!`?

Comment: try with checking null on `widget.model!.thumbnailUrl!,` also you can try `widget.model?.thumbnailUrl??"",`

Comment: Please print the value of `widget.model!.thumbnailUrl!` and add the output to the question.

Comment: widget.model?.thumbnailUrl??"",  this is showing same error .

Comment: Value of What is widget.model!.thumbnailUrl!? Is image uploaded in firebase .. @jamesdlin if i put some image url as argument it is working but not this widget.model!.thumbnailUrl!

Comment: Again: what is the output if you add `print(widget.model!.thumbnailUrl);` before using `Image.network`?

Comment: @jamesdlin Error: This expression has type 'void' and can't be used.
              print(widget.model!.thumbnailUrl!),
              ^                                                                                         this is the error if i try to print before Image.network

Comment: @RamakrishnaKannari It's a separate *statement*; you can't use it as an *argument* to another function.  This is all very basic syntax.  I suggest you start with a more basic tutorial, and read the [Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour).